# How is code block highlighted?

Tags: discussion, source-code

How does it work, that code blocks are formatted, highlighted and colored? Does SE use any of general available JavaScript libraries, like SyntaxHighlighter, or does it have its own engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses Google Prettify

See how to set language in code blocks here
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

This has been discussed before here:
[Manually specify language for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting)